# Change Gender Voice from Python gtts library

Tags: python, gtts

I found this code to get Speech from text.
Is there a way to change the gender of the voice?

```
from gtts import gTTS

tts = gTTS(text='Hello, how are you?', lang='en-IN')
tts.save('hello2.mp3')

print("finish")
```

I found this parameters:

```
Afrikaans (Südafrika)   Standard    af-ZA   af-ZA-Standard-A    WEIBLICH    
Arabisch    Standard    ar-XA   ar-XA-Standard-A    WEIBLICH    
Arabisch    Standard    ar-XA   ar-XA-Standard-B    MÄNNLICH    
Arabisch    Standard    ar-XA   ar-XA-Standard-C    MÄNNLICH    
Arabisch    Standard    ar-XA   ar-XA-Standard-D    WEIBLICH    
Arabisch    WaveNet ar-XA   ar-XA-Wavenet-A WEIBLICH    
Arabisch    WaveNet ar-XA   ar-XA-Wavenet-B MÄNNLICH    
Arabisch    WaveNet ar-XA   ar-XA-Wavenet-C MÄNNLICH    
Arabisch    WaveNet ar-XA   ar-XA-Wavenet-D WEIBLICH    
Bengalisch (Indien) Standard    bn-IN   bn-IN-Standard-A    WEIBLICH    
Bengalisch (Indien) Standard    bn-IN   bn-IN-Standard-B    MÄNNLICH    
Bengalisch (Indien) WaveNet bn-IN   bn-IN-Wavenet-A WEIBLICH    
Bengalisch (Indien) WaveNet bn-IN   bn-IN-Wavenet-B MÄNNLICH    
Bulgarisch (Bulgarien)  Standard    bg-BG   bg-bg-Standard-A    WEIBLICH    
Katalanisch (Spanien)   Standard    ca-ES   ca-es-Standard-A    WEIBLICH    
Chinesisch (Hongkong)   Standard    yue-HK  yue-HK-Standard-A   WEIBLICH    
Chinesisch (Hongkong)   Standard    yue-HK  yue-HK-Standard-B   MÄNNLICH    
Chinesisch (Hongkong)   Standard    yue-HK  yue-HK-Standard-C   WEIBLICH    
Chinesisch (Hongkong)   Standard    yue-HK  yue-HK-Standard-D   MÄNNLICH    
Tschechisch (Tschechische Republik) Standard    cs-CZ   cs-CZ-Standard-A    WEIBLICH    
Tschechisch (Tschechische Republik) WaveNet cs-CZ   cs-CZ-Wavenet-A WEIBLICH    
Dänisch (Dänemark)  Standard    da-DK   da-DK-Standard-A    WEIBLICH    
Dänisch (Dänemark)  Standard    da-DK   da-DK-Standard-C    MÄNNLICH
```